# On attempt to install Signal, I think I made some mistake and now getting some error in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. How to correct this? Thank you

Tags: signal

On sudo apt update command I get the following output:

```
> sudo apt update
[sudo] password for chess: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:2 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic InRelease                                                  
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                              
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease                                                       
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/foliate/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                      
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:7 http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease                                                                           
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                             
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                         
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
Hit:11 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease                                                      
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ernstp/mesarc/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                         
Hit:14 https://deb.opera.com/opera-developer stable InRelease                                                                
Hit:15 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                               
Hit:16 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                    
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                  
Hit:18 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                             
Hit:20 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelebek333/kablosuz/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:22 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease              
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease               
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rvm/smplayer/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gfeeds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xuzhen666/gnome-mpv/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:3

~ took 1m4s
```

If someone knows how can we rectify this, it will help me. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: With so many PPAs and third-party repositories, it's a marvel that your system boots at all. It's impressive, showing how resilient Ubuntu is. However, it does suggest that you need regular backups -- such a frankensystem will surely fail eventually.

Comment: You've added the same repository multiple times. That's basically what the messages are telling you: "Target ... is configured multiple times in ...". Look at the files and lines given in the messages (like `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list`, lines 1 and 2) and remove the additional entries.

Comment: @Henning thank you for telling me that. I have now deleted that particular signal file and running the commands again and I get   All packages are up to date.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.  So I am now running command which is given in this error. If it works, thanks to you. :)

Comment: @user535733, this Linux, it is working quite well and only faster than windows. I had 1.5 to 2 time applications running over when I was using Windows previously, many of them were even in start up process list. I had no problems even then. But thank you for telling me to take a back up. Thanks.

Comment: @user535733 frankensystem meaning?

Comment: @Henning your answer worked. Installed it successfully. I have marked it yes, upvote. Thanks you.. :)

Comment: "Frankensystem" probably refers to [Frankenstein's monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein%27s_monster). The prefix "franken-" is occasionally used to describe things that [are cobbled together from disparate elements](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/franken-), where the outcome isn't exactly attractive or reliable ;)

Comment: Doesn't seem a good word to use then right. ;)  One may write there are many applications, will require more system resources (which I have) and it is advisable to take back up. (Also here everything is working only better as compared to Windows 10.)